# Android: ScrollView and RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I making a layout and I need to add a scrollview apart from all compoments. The thing is as you can see on the image below that the RelativeLayout where I place all me compoments for some reason does not fill the parent and instead wrap the contents. But this affect the ExpandableListView where only shows one group item with no childs. I want my RelativeLayout to fill parent not to wrap. You may say that the expandable list may cause this but I tried and without that and again is wrap the contents and not fill the parent.

**activity_product.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
           android:id="@+id/slider"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           custom:pager_animation="Default"
           custom:auto_cycle="true"
           custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
           custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="-35%"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:layout_marginBottom="71dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


   </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Screenshot**
[image]

Comment: First of all you can't use Scroll container view inside Scrollable View and how you actually want to show ?

Comment: I edit my answer that and without the expandable list the same problem exists. Well I want to be all the activity scrollable and inside the activity on the top I'll have an image viewer and below that an expandable list with some childs. If for some reason the childs are many and can't shown on the screen when you scroll down to see them the whole activity scrolls and not just the list.

Comment: why your parent LineraLayout has android:layout_height="wrap_content" ?? isn't it supposed to fill the height of the activity?

Comment: My mistake. I my code I have it fill but on copy-paste I change it accidentally.

Comment: You can try this hack on: [How to Make Android ListView or GridView Expandable inside ScrollView](http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/make-android-listview-gridview-expandable-inside-scrollview/) I used it in the past and it worked on an expandable list.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"/>
```

**header.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="-35%"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:background="@color/orange"/>

    <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        custom:pager_animation="Default"
        custom:auto_cycle="true"
        custom:indicator_visibility="visible"
        custom:pager_animation_span="1100"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    private TextView textView;
    private SliderLayout slider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.header,null);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        slider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        expandableListView.addHeaderView(header);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(YourExpandableListViewAdapterHere);

    }
}
```